# How to change a Schengen Visa valid for only 20 days?

Tags: visas, schengen

I applied for Schengen Visa at Italian Consulate in New York. It was given valid for only 20 days. I asked for 2 entries 10 days in 2 different countries while the 2 entries are 30 days apart as I leave for India in between. They gave 2 entries and 10 days stay. But they probably did not see my tickets and the visa expires before my second entry, which is into Italy. There is no phone to contact and you can only contact them via email, which I am waiting for 3 days now.

Comment: they gave 20 continuous days instead of two periods of 10 continuous days? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually I made a trip such that I stop in Spain for 2 days and go to India for 30 days, while returning to US I stop in Italy 8 days. The total trip from begin to end is 40 days out of that 2 in Spain, 30 in India and 8 in Italy. They only gave visa valid for 20 days, so it will expire after I visit Spain and while I am in India.

Comment: so why did you write "They gave 2 entries and 10 days stay"? Even though now I understand your problem, you should update your question to remove this and to make clear that you have a long break between your two entries.

Comment: Is it that when I enter Spain they'll(Spain authorities at the airport) extend the Visa or is this something that surely needs correction ? What is 90 days validity ? I'm reading on forums Type C visas are valid for 90 days. That's not the true in my case ?

Comment: I don't know, do you have a type C visa?

Comment: Yeah my Visa Category Says Type 'C'.

Comment: @Neha the 90 in 180 day validity doesn't apply to your visa even though it's type C

Comment: Italian consulate is not responding. I think I'll have to go for another Schengen visa appointment at the Italian Consulate. Can they put 2 valid visas on the passports ? Although for different validity periods ?

Comment: @Neha There is nothing stopping them from doing so.

Answer (score 3):

As you wrote yourself in your comments already, you need to have an additional visa.
One choice is that you get another visa for the second entry, or you organize for a multiple entry visa.

The multiple entry visa however will likely only be granted if you have traveled to Europe several times before that.

Since your two entries are one month apart from each other, there should be no issue for them giving you an additional visa, since the minimum period for a visa is three months before the trip.